# blueimp jquery uploader - on loaded, MB label changes to KB label

Tags: blueimp

Using Blueimp jquery uploader with php. When I upload a file of size XX MB, on finishing the upload, the progress area refreshes with the link, size & "Clear" button, as expected, except:

The "MB" label changes to "KB"

The actual size is still correct, it just displays the wrong units

Ex: A 4.5MB file displays as 4.5KB

Where can I find this area of the code to try to track this down? I'm not overriding anything in this "finished" code

Answer (score 0):

$('.size').text().replace('KB', 'MB');

Comment: that's a silly answer. I'm not trying to change the label; I'm looking for the code bug that is causing it in the first place. I don't always know that the label is the incorrect unit